# How to download rftd file from Google Drive (Objective C, iOS)

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I am able to download files from Google drive ok, but how do you download rtfd files since Google Drive sees them as folders?

The mime type is: mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
And when trying to download the file by identifier, the error 403 occurs.
Thanks

Comment: [The rtfd file is the folder including the files.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format_Directory) So the mimeType becomes `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` on Google Drive. If you want to download it, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve the file IDs in the folder of the rtfd file using the folder ID of the rtfd file. 2. Download the files using the retrieved IDs. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks. What I am wondering about is when I save it on the iPad (using iOS), do I need to then create a folder with .rtfd extension then move the files into it to recreate the folder on the iPad?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your replying, I couldn't see it in the question. So can you update your question by including the detail information of your goal? By this, it will help users think of your goal and the solution.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I got it! I was confusing .rtf with .rtfd which is really a folder. It makes sense now. Thank you!